# Font awesome showing asian signs instead of icons

Tags: firefox, icons, opera, chromium, font-awesome

i'm trying to use Font Awesome but instead of any icons it just displays any asian signs. I downloaded font awsome to by webserver for that. I tried this in 3 different browsers (firefox, opera and chromium) but it is always the same.

A testpage can be seen here: http://2weitweitweg.de/test.html

And here is a screenshot of it: http://postimg.org/image/9yh5p0p97/

Does it show the signs in your browser? Is the problem browser- or server-related? How can i fix it?

bye

Answer (score 9):

I had this problem and it was because I was using old html with a new [fontawesome](http://fontawesome.io/) version.

**I fixed it by changing:**

```
<i class="fa-bitbucket"></i>
```

**to:**

```
<i class="fa fa-bitbucket"></i>
```

I.e. I just had to add the default `fa` class to the element.

The latest version uses the `fa` prefix but for you, I guess it might be `icon` instead.

Hope this helps someone out at some stage :-)

Answer (score 5):

Most likely the actual font files are not being found. If you look in the font awesome CSS file you will probably see something like:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot');
  src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    [...etc]
```

This expects to find the font files in a folder called font at the same level that the CSS file is in. For example:

```
myproject / css
                 / font-awesome.css
                   [...etc]
          / font
                 / fontawesome-webfont.eot
                   [...etc]
```

If the files are in the correct place it is possible that they are not being loaded because of some problem with permissions or even that you have are using a strange browser that does not properly support @font-face. Of course you can rule out the latter by browsing to the [font awesome examples page](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/) to see if it displays the icons properly.

Comment: if the html file which should show the text is not in myproject but in any different folder...Does the path to the font-files have to be relative with the path of the css file as "root" or is the html file which includes the css file the root?

Answer (score 2):

Hope I'm not too late, something on your server isn't configured properly, solution is to allow *.woff and *.tff to be requested like static resources just like you do with *.css and *.js, this is done differently depending on platform:

[image]

What I did to make it work:

Replaced your stylesheet with (since we can't get to resources):

```
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.0.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And replaced your old icon-* classes, for example:

```
<i class="fa-umbrella fa text-error"></i>
```

And now it works:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you using 4.0 or later, they've changed the `icon` classes to `fa` classes
So your code should say

```
    <i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-large"></i>
```

instead of

```
    <i class="icon icon-camera-retro icon-large"></i>
```

You can find icon, specific code examples by visiting http://fontawesome.io/icons/ and clicking/tapping the icon you need.

I had this same issue when upgrading from 3.2 to 4.0.3

Answer (score 0):

Run the below command

npx react-native link react-native-vector-icons

Answer (score 0):

Using fontawesone 5.15.1 I had to do this to get the Linux icon to show up:

```
<i class="fab fa-linux icon"></i>
```

IMPORTANT: using "**fab**" instead of "fa" as Linux is considered a "brand".